# Why does opening and closing a Dialog in Meterial-UI remove a style from my body attribute?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the parent component, I am modifying the body with a couple styles when the component mounts:

```
document.body.style.overflowX = "hidden";
document.body.style.width = "100%";
```

In my parent component is the Dialog child component, however when I open and close the dialog then the `overflow` attribute is removed, while the `width` attribute remains. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a Material-UI `Modal` (`Dialog` leverages `Modal`) is opened, it disables scrolling of the page content behind the `Modal` while it is open. It accomplishes this by setting [`style.overflow = 'hidden';`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.3/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/ModalManager.js#L70) on the container of the `Modal`.

Material-UI does [remember the previous setting](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.3.3/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/ModalManager.js#L68) of the `overflow` property so that it can restore the setting when the `Modal` closes.

The reason you do not see your setting restored is because you are using `overflow-x` rather than `overflow`. When Material-UI sets the `overflow` CSS, the browser (at least in Chrome) wipes out the `overflow-x` setting, but Material-UI only restores the `overflow` setting (not `overflow-x`).

If you change your code to set `overflow` instead (e.g. `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden auto";` sets overflow-x to "hidden" and overflow-y to "auto"), it will be successfully restored by Material-UI when the `Dialog` closes.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dialog-with-overflow-set-on-document-body-1npp0